# Recyclerview not updating data when filtered with searchview

Tags: java, android, filtering, searchview

So i have a searchview in my tabbed activity with 5 fragments and when i search for something in fragment 1 (Tab1) it filters my recyclerview correctly with the searched song.

But it still plays the song from the list with all my songs and not the song from filtered list.

So for example in fragment 1 i have 5 songs and i search for the 5th song, but when i try to play the 5th song it still plays my first song.

So my recyclerview is not updating my arraylist with the filtered arraylist.

**Main.musicList** is a global arraylist from another activity which stores all songs from device.

**StorageUtil** is a helper class which stores my arraylist with the songs and song  index so i can play the song.

How can i do this?

Thanks,

**Activity**

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
    for(int i = 0; i < pagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {

        Fragment viewPagerFragment = (Fragment) mViewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(mViewPager, i);
        if(viewPagerFragment != null && viewPagerFragment.isAdded()) {

            if (viewPagerFragment instanceof Tab1){
                Tab1 tab1 = (Tab1) viewPagerFragment;
                if (tab1 != null){
                    tab1.beginSearch(newText); // Calling the method beginSearch of Tab1
                    if (newText == null || newText.trim().isEmpty()) {
                        tab1.resetSearch();
                    }
                }
            }else if (viewPagerFragment instanceof Tab2){
                Tab2 tab2 = (Tab2) viewPagerFragment;
                if (tab2 != null){
                    //tab2.beginSearch(query); // Calling the method beginSearch of Tab2
                }
            }else if (viewPagerFragment instanceof Tab3){
                Tab3 tab3 = (Tab3) viewPagerFragment;
                if (tab3 != null){
                    //tab3.beginSearch(query); // Calling the method beginSearch of Tab3
                }
            }else if (viewPagerFragment instanceof Tab4){
                Tab4 tab4 = (Tab4) viewPagerFragment;
                if (tab4 != null){
                    //tab4.beginSearch(query); // Calling the method beginSearch of Tab4
                }
            }else if (viewPagerFragment instanceof Tab5){
                Tab5 tab5 = (Tab5) viewPagerFragment;
                if (tab5 != null){
                    //tab5.beginSearch(query); // Calling the method beginSearch of Tab5
                }
            }
        }
    }        
    return false;
```

**Fragment (Tab1)**

```
private void initRecyclerView() {
    Main.musicList = Main.songs.songs;
    // Connects the song list to an adapter
    // (thing that creates several Layouts from the song list)
    if ((Main.musicList != null) && (!Main.musicList.isEmpty())) {
        allSongsAdapter = new AllSongsAdapter(getContext(), Main.musicList);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerViewSongs.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerViewSongs.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewSongs.setAdapter(allSongsAdapter);
        Log.i(TAG, "Songs found in list!");

        recyclerViewSongs.addOnItemTouchListener(new OnItemClickListeners(getContext(), new OnItemClickListeners.OnItemClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You Clicked position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Start playing the selected song.
                playAudio(position);

            }
        }));

    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "No songs found in list!");
    }
}

public void beginSearch(String query) {
    Log.e("QueryFragment", query);
    allSongsAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
}

public void resetSearch(){
    allSongsAdapter = new AllSongsAdapter(getContext(), Main.musicList);
    recyclerViewSongs.setAdapter(allSongsAdapter);
}

private void playAudio(int songIndex) {
    //MediaService is active
    //Store songList and songIndex in mSharedPreferences
    StorageUtil storageUtil = new StorageUtil(getContext());
    storageUtil.storeSong(Main.musicList);
    storageUtil.storeSongIndex(songIndex);
    //Send media with BroadcastReceiver
    Intent broadCastReceiverIntent = new Intent(Constants.ACTIONS.BROADCAST_PlAY_NEW_SONG);
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(broadCastReceiverIntent);
    }
    //Send media with BroadcastReceiver
    Intent broadCastReceiverIntentUpdateSong = new Intent(Constants.ACTIONS.BROADCAST_UPDATE_SONG);
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(broadCastReceiverIntentUpdateSong);
    }
}
```

**Adapter with searchview filter**

```
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (valueFilter == null) {
        valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
    }
    return valueFilter;
}

private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        String str = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
        Log.e("constraint", str);
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<Song> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < filteredMusicList.size(); i++) {
                if ((filteredMusicList.get(i).getTitle().toUpperCase())
                        .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                    Song song = filteredMusicList.get(i);
                    filterList.add(song);
                }
            }
            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values = filterList;
        } else {
            results.count = filteredMusicList.size();
            results.values = filteredMusicList;
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        musicList = (ArrayList<Song>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**Edit (Working but not sure if it's the right way to do it)**

In my adapters i call my helper class StorageUtil that stores my music list and i store the filtered musiclist then i made a broadcastreceiver which sends a broadcast that my musiclist is updated.

```
   @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        musicList = (ArrayList<Song>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        StorageUtil storageUtil = new StorageUtil(context);
        storageUtil.storeSong(musicList);

        Intent broadCastReceiverIntent = new Intent(Constants.ACTIONS.BROADCAST_UPDATE_MUSICLIST);
        context.sendBroadcast(broadCastReceiverIntent);
    }
```

**And in my fragment i set the musiclist to the filtered list**

```
  //Register BroadCastReceiver UPDATE_SONG
private void registerUpdateMusicListBroadCastReceiver(){
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Constants.ACTIONS.BROADCAST_UPDATE_MUSICLIST);
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        getActivity().registerReceiver(UpdateMusicListBroadCastReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

}

private BroadcastReceiver UpdateMusicListBroadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        StorageUtil storageUtil = new StorageUtil(getContext());
        Main.musicList = storageUtil.getSongs();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how to you get the music index.
There is only one item in list when you filter the music list.
So position of it always is 0 in the list.
You should get index of selected item in the real music list (Main.musicList).

Comment: Right, but i get the music index from the position where the user clicks but how to get the position when the list is filtered?

Comment: You can put real index of item in related object.

Comment: Can you check my edit its working but i'm not sure its the right way to do it.

Comment: The only thing to note is that you can use a library such as EventBus instead of Broadcast.

Comment: What's the difference between those two?

Comment: The broadcast handles by OS but libraries like EventBus works in App context.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem please verify my answer. @Vince